# Block discount on certain product shopify script

Tags: ruby, shopify

I want to write a script in Shopify that prevents discounts from rendering on certain products. I know this is wrong, but something like this:

```
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  product = line_item.variant.product

  if product = 123456789
     CartDiscount.remove("Discount does not apply")
  end

end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/shopify-scripts) and saw the `.reject({ message: String })` method but it applies to the whole cart. Is there a way to localize this to one instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but I found a resolution: basically, you can't "localize" a discount to a specific product. You have to block the entire cart from getting a discount. The approach I ended up taking is below:

```
# ID of product you want to block
productId = 10199241991

# Runs through a loop of items in your cart
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  product = line_item.variant.product
  puts product.id
  next if product.gift_card?
  next unless product.id == productId
  case Input.cart.discount_code
  when CartDiscount::Percentage
    Input.cart.discount_code.reject({message: "Cannot be used with this product"})
  end
end


Output.cart = Input.cart
```

Answer (score 0):

Discounts are easy. First... get the discount code from the cart. You know it applies to the whole cart. Now you have an amount, or percentage or whatever you gave the customer in the code. Now kicks in the beauty of the scripts.

For each product, decide if it is discounted or not. If it is, apply the discount amount that you know from the discount code provided to the item. If it is a product not to be discounted, leave the price alone.

You are paying big bucks for the scripting engine. If you cannot program it yourself, pay someone that can! You are way better off studying a working script to learn, that trying to outfox yourself.

So you can in fact reject the discount code for the cart, but still discount products, some, not all, or others.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question - I want to localize the `.reject({ message: String })` to a single product, but still apply the discount to other items in the cart where applicable. Is this possible?